# Application logs in windows 2008 is showing empty

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Application logs in windows 2008 is showing zero event.

Issue is re-occurring, all others logs are showing events but application logs in eventvwr is showing empty.

Tried to access application logs from powershell and getting below error:

**PS Y:> get-eventlog application
Get-EventLog : The file size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be saved
At line:1 char:13
+ get-eventlog <<<<  application
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand**

Issue gets resolved after renaming application log file but re-occur again.

Checked and found size limit is 262144 KB however application log file only of 66560 KB

Comment: Make sure the Application event log doesn't have a filter being applied to it that's giving 0 results.  Right-click the application log and look for an option to "Clear Filter."  If that isn't an option, there's no filter.

Comment: @Morrow: Filter is not applied
SimonS: Yes, issue get resolved after renaming application log (.evtx) file but issue comes again. It is only happening on application logs, system and other logs are working fine.

Comment: @Morrow: Filter is not applied

Answer (score 1):

you can access the eventlog with `Get-Eventlog` but i think you need to specify more things

```
$Events = Get-Eventlog -LogName application -Entrytype Error -Newest 200
```

This example will only list the Error Events of the newest 200 events in application log

```
$Events | format-list *
```

will show you all properties.

To the problem with Eventlog showing no entries try to rename the log file as it was answered here:
[Can not see entries in Application Log in Event Viewer](https://serverfault.com/questions/348237/can-not-see-entries-in-application-log-in-event-viewer)

Comment: Yes, issue get resolved after renaming application log (.evtx) file but issue comes again. It is only happening on application logs, system and other logs are working fine.

Comment: Also, when i am trying to check the application logs via powershell, i am getting below error however size limit is 262144 KB and application log file is only of 66560 KB



PS Y:> get-eventlog application Get-EventLog : The file size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be saved At line:1 char:13 + get-eventlog <<<< application + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], Win32Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand

Comment: @NitinKhanna Click on application log > properties - what do you see there? please post a screenshot or something.

Comment: it should be similar to System and security eventlog properties. if you're not sure, post a screenshot. Did you try to read the eventlog with my powershell command?

Comment: also, create a completely new .evtx for application eventlog. sorry for so many comments...

Comment: I cannot put screenshot due to security reasons, issue get resolved after creating completely new .evtx for application log...but issue is coming again and again....i will use powershell command which you have provided if issue comes again...thanks....i will be back on this